# How do I find the range of this array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, insert, pass-by-reference

So I'm writing a method where I insert a bunch of numbers into a dynamic array (and increase the size if there's not enough room. I already wrote an insert method that inserts only one value into the array and this method just inserts a bunch of values into the array. It starts out like this:

```
void dynamic_array::insert(dynamic_array &a, int i) {
```

Where it takes in a pointer for a dynamic array. The thing is it's easy to figure out how to insert the values but I need to find the range of the numbers that I'm inserting. So given a dynamic array pass by reference, how do I find the range of that array?

Comment: what do you mean by range? Do you want to be able to insert a range of elements into the array, for example 1,4,5,6 in one function call?

Comment: Basically what it's doing is inserting a bunch of values into a dynamic array. So let's say the dynamic_array &a is 4 5 6 and the i is 2and it's inserting it into another array which has the values 2 3 7 9 8 then after the insert is called, the array should look like 2 3 7 4 5 6 9 8. So basically if the array that's being inserted is 4 5 6 then the range would be 3 because it's inserting 3 values.

Comment: surely your dynamic array has a `size()` function to get the number of elements in the array?

Comment: I do have a get_size function for my main dynamic array however in the insert method it's calling an array a. Could my get_size function work for the other array?

Comment: the `a` in your insert function prototype is of type `dynamic_array`, so it should work.